# R Terminal not entering in Command prompt

Tags: r, process, cmd

I have use the following code snippet to enter the r terminal in command prompt through process from console application

```
Process cmdProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName="cmd.exe",
                    Arguments =" /C R.exe",
                    UseShellExecute=false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput=true,
                    RedirectStandardError=true,
                    CreateNoWindow=true
                }
            };

            cmdProcess.Start();

            string result=string.Empty;

            if(!cmdProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                result += cmdProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + "\n";
            }

            if(!cmdProcess.StandardError.EndOfStream)
            {
                result += cmdProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd() + "\n";
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);            
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I need to enter the r terminal through process and get the out put for each line of r script by writting r code in standardinput of process(sream writter) but i got the following error in standard output of command prompt while entering r terminal

Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla

Answer (score 0):

Change line 6 to:

```
Arguments =" /C R.exe --vanilla",
```

There is a little more information about batch processing with R [here](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/batch.html).